# C# List property initialisation patterns

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns

I always see these two initialisation patterns used in every day code. I was just looking for a definitive reason as to why you would opt for one over the other, other than preference?

**Pattern 1**

```
public class School
{
    private List<User> _users;

    public School()
    {
        _users = new List<User>();
    }

    public List<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Pattern 2**

```
public class School
{
    public School()
    {
        this.Users = new List<User>();
    }
    public List<User> Users { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I find the second much more readable; don't you? Also, I greatly value my screen real estate, so the second allows me to see more code at a time, which further aids my comprehension.

Comment: Yes I personally use the second pattern, unless I need to transform the backing variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are essentially the same. First one only makes a difference if you do anything particular in the get or set, otherwise the 2nd one is more compact and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same thing.  The 2nd is "syntactic sugar", which means the compiler basically takes care of the repetitive typing for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to the backing variable, then use the first.  Otherwise, use the second and let the .NET framework generate the backing variable for you.

Although, I will say that exposing an `IList` as a public property isn't always a great idea, as you open your class' list to full modification.  If all you want to do is expose the contents of the `IList`, consider implementing an [enumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Pattern 2 is using an auto property. If you don't need access to the backing field then don't put one in. You can always add it later. This is a form of encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable need a default value, usually I used this pattern:

```
public class School
{
    private List<User> _users = new List<Users>();
    public List<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        set
        {
            _users = value;
        }
    }
}
```

At least until I learn API design. After that, usually I used this pattern (this may related to David Hoerster's answer):

```
public class School
{
    List<User> _users = new List<Users>();
    public IEnumerable<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return _users;
        }
        set
        {
            _users.Clean();
            _users.AddRange(value);
        }
    }

    public void AddUser(User user){
      _users.Add(user);
    }
}
```

Some of the reasons:

- I know immediaetly that the property has default value, not tracking to the constructor.
- It support better abstraction, since you can insert other enumeration other than List, such as ObservableCollection, or even pure array (User[])

It may have some code smells though, but I prefer it better than having a concrete List object.